# Changing images when next or previous are clicked

Tags: javascript

everyone.I want my hidden_div img to change after clicking prev. or next.Is it possible  using this  JS code?

```
    <a href="#"><div onClick="show(this);" class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img1.jpg');")></div></a>
   <a href="#"><div onClick="show(this);" class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img2.jpg');")></div></a>
   <a href="#"><div onClick="show(this);" class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img3.jpg');")></div></a>

<div id="hidden_div"></div>
<a href="#" onClik="next(-1)">prev</a>
<a href="#" onClik="next(1)">next</a>


<script>
function show(element) {
    var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden_div"); 
    var imgURL = element.style.backgroundImage.replace('url(','').replace(')','');    
    var imgElement = "<img src="+ imgURL +" />" 
    hidden.innerHTML  = imgElement;
};

var step=1;
var total=3;
 function next(x){ 
    var image=document.getElementById("hidden_div");

    step=step+x;
    if(step > total){step=1;}
     if(step <1 ){step=total;}
     image.src= 'css/images1/img/img " + step + ".jpg';
   };
```

Comment: This is a very strange way to build a gallery  but everyone to their own. I'm doing to assume the divs with the class img are the thumbs to the gallery and the hidden_div is the main display for the image?

Comment: Yes, you are right.Actually the second part of my JS is a trial version. Do you have an easier way do connect 2 parts of my code? I want a slider something like facebook , when an image is clicked.I thought this way.

Comment: It's very possible but the reason I haven't submitted an answer is because the way I would correct your next/step function is by making changes to the way the gallery works, that would lead into too many changes and could be classed as me reconstructing your source code rather than fixing the problem in hand, sorry.

Comment: Oh, don't be sorry, my dear friend,It is ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the src change isn't working is because in your `next()` function you are trying to set the src attribute to a div element, not the image inside of it.

The image you want to change doesn't have an id so to target the image inside of your div tag you will want to use `getElementById()` to target the div and attach `getElementsByTagName` to target the `<img>`.

```
 getElementById().getElementsByTagName()[0]
```

---

```
function next(x){ 
    step=step+x;
    if(step > total){step=1;}
     if(step <1 ){step=total;}
     document.getElementById("hidden_div").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src='css/images1/img/img'+step+'.jpg'
}
```

If you have any questions about the answer, please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible. (*Understanding the source code is just as important as getting the answer!*)

> **Edit:** Working Demo...

Also note, your anchor tag to trigger the next function is incorrect.

```
<a href="#" onClik="next(-1)">prev</a>
```

`onClik` should be `onClick`. Simple typing error but makes a big difference when it comes to code.

```js
function show(element) {
    var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden_div"); 
    var imgURL = element.style.backgroundImage.replace('url(','').replace(')','');    
    var imgElement = "<img src="+ imgURL +" />" 
    hidden.innerHTML  = imgElement;
}
var total=3;
var step=1;
 function next(x){ 
    step=step+x;
    if(step > total){step=1;}
     if(step <1 ){step=total;}
     document.getElementById("hidden_div").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src='https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text='+step+'.jpg'
   }
```

```css
.img{height:150px;width:150px;border:solid red 1px;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div onClick="show(this);" class="img" style="background-image:url('https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=1.jpg');")>1</div>
<div onClick="show(this);" class="img" style="background-image:url('https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=2.jpg');")>2</div>
<div onClick="show(this);" class="img" style="background-image:url('https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=3.jpg');")>3</div><br/>
<button onClick="next(-1);">Prev</button><button onClick="next(1);">Next</button>
<div id="hidden_div"></div>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank u for your answer, but it still doesn't work.I think maybe the reason is that i insert the img by JS.

Comment: This fixes the step/next function as asked. I will look at your show function too, give me a moment.

Comment: No, it didn't help. I even changed the <a> tag to another tag<p> in order to be sure.

Comment: Working demo to show you this works. It's possible you have other problems with your source code but this answers your question on how to fix the next function. Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Ok, I 'll check my code once more time.Thank your very much for your help and time.:)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the undefined variables step1 and total1. Can you try replacing those variables with step and total.

```
function next(x)
{ 
    var image=document.getElementById("hidden_div");
    var step=step+x;
    if(step > total) 
       step=1;
    else if(step <1 )
       step=total;
    image.src= 'css/images1/img/img'+step+'.jpg';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work.I made corrections in my code.

Comment: Are you sure the src path you are giving is correct?

Comment: Yes.I am sure.I simply copied and pasted.

Comment: Try giving this as src  'css/images1/img/img'+ step + '.jpg'